# How to set variables to custom function in Jmeter?

Tags: variables, jmeter

I have a basic function in BeanShellSampler.bshrc at Jmeter 4.0

```
String getMyString(String strParam) {
return "MyString: "+strParam; 
}
```

I called in BeanShell Sampler as below

```
String N = "123123";
log.info("${__BeanShell(getMyString("${__V(Var${N})}"),)}");
```

When I run Sampler output is somthing like that.

```
2018-06-18 15:25:40,080 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: MyString: Var${N}
```

How can I set string variable to my function?

I read function articles in [Jmeter web site](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#what_can_do)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   beanshell.sampler.init=BeanShellSampler.bshrc
   ```
2. Amend your code to look like:

   ```
   String N = "123123";
   log.info(getMyString(N));
   ```
3. That's it, you should get `MyString: 123123` in *jmeter.log* file

   [image: JMeter Beanshell Function]

---

Be aware that [starting from Jmeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for all forms of scripting as [Groovy performance is much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so consider taking the following steps instead:

1. Create a file, i.e. `foo.groovy` in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and put your function there:

   ```
   String getMyString(String strParam) {
       return "MyString: " + strParam;
   }
   ```
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:
3. You should be able to refer your custom code from [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(log.info(getMyString("123123")),)}
   ```

   functions can be used anywhere in the Test Plan

   [image: JMeter Groovy Function]

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri. I have not added my functions to BeanShellSampler.bshrc file. You solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For each BeanShell Program type there are different `beanshell.*.init` properties defined in `bin/user.properties`

```
beanshell.function.init=BeanShellFunction.bshrc

beanshell.preprocessor.init=BeanShellSampler.bshrc

beanshell.postprocessor.init=BeanShellSampler.bshrc 

beanshell.assertion.init=BeanShellFunction.bshrc
```

Hence the same function which needs to be called from any program(preprocessor, postprocessor, etc) we need to copy the function to every .bshrc file OR use same .bshrc file for every program init property.

In your case if you are using local string variable `N` and passing it along with the script. If you use ${Variable} there must be a JMeter variable defined so that JMeter can pick its value. To do that you can use vars.put , write N value to JMeter variables and use ${N} .

I have defined `Var123123` value as `FinalValue` as shown below 
[image]

And 2 beanshell samplers one is to put String variable N to Jmeter variable and one is beanshell script as shown below [image]
[image]

You can see in the log its printed `VAR123123`'s value which is `FinalValue`

The reason why i took 2 beashell samplers is if i write `N` to JMeter variables and use it in same script its not updating N value until the sampler executed..

References :

[Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)

[JMeter Beanshell](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/4878/)

Please let me know if it helps